# Constructing a Abelian group from a von Neumann ordinal

Tags: group-theory, set-theory, abelian-groups, ordinals, well-orders

Suppose we have an ordinal, $a$, that is defined in the standard von Neumann way. Can we create a binary operation $+:a^2\to a$, such that $(a,+)$ is an Abelian group? Specifically, I would like $+$  to be defined with standard set-theoretical means. One solution I thought of was to define a function, $S:a\to a$, such that
$$
S(x)= \begin{cases}
\emptyset&\text{if } x = \sup(a)\\
x\cup \{x\}&\text{else}
\end{cases}$$
From this, we could then define $S^{[y]}(x)$ as the $y$th composition of $S$ with itself. Specifically that
$$S^{[y]}(x)=(\underset{i\in y}{C} S)(x)$$
(I assume that $S^{[y]}(x)=S^{[x]}(y)$ but I do not know how to prove this, so I may be mistaken.) From this we can define $x+y:= S^{[x]}(y)$. We can see that all group axioms are satisfied here. There is an additive identity ($0$), there also exist inverses ($(a-x) + x=0$), and the operation is closed.

But then, it seems that all groups formed are cyclic, and then the group made from $\omega_0$ would be isomorphic to the one from $\omega_1$, by virtue of $\mathbb{Z}$ being the only infinite cyclic group, thus the cardinality of the $\omega_1$ group would be equal to $\aleph_0$, which is smaller than the cardinality of $\omega_1$. This seems paradoxical, so I assume there is a flaw in my construction. What is the flaw, and how would I go about properly constructing a group from an ordinal?

---

**Edit:** In the comments, I've been informed that what I have is not guaranteed to be a group. I was confused by the existence of $\omega_0+1$ and thought that there also existed $\omega_0-1$, which is false. In which case, the problem remains of how to construct a group from an ordinal.

---

**Edit 2:** From the comments, it seems like there, in fact, is a group operation over every ordinal. But the question remains of is such a group operation definable in a "natural" way, using only basic set operations such as union and intersection. Ideally, the group operation should also be such that if $a$ and $b$ are ordinals, $(a,+_a)\cong (b,+_b)$ if and only if $|a| = |b|$. The goal here is to be able to construct groups of arbitrary size.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk using it as notation for repeated composition, I've seen it somewhere before but I don't know if its standard.

Comment: Thanks -- I realized after I commented that you tacitly explained this. Anyway, you'll need to be precise about the definition of $S^{[y]}(x)$ when $y$ is a limit ordinal in order for this to make sense.

Comment: I think i see two flaws. The first one is on the definition of $S^{y}$, you have to have the limit case on your definition and $a-x$ is not an ordinal!

Comment: Additionally, I don't see any reason why these groups would be cyclic in general. The subgroup generated by $0 \in a$ (when $a$ is infinite) will be $\omega_0$, not all of $a$.

Comment: For a specific counterexample to the existence of inverses, consider $a = \omega_0$. There is no $x \in a$ such that $S^{[x]}(1) = 0$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk After googling it, I think I was confused. My impression was that you could do all of the standard arithmetic on limit ordinals, but after a quick google search, I guess there is no such thing as $\omega_0-1$ or $\sup(\omega_0)$?

Comment: Correct, there is no such thing as $\omega_0 - 1$. There *is* such thing as $\sup \omega_0$, but this is equal to $\omega_0$, which is not an element of $\omega_0$.

Comment: You can always use transport of structure, but I'm guessing that's not what you want to do.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: is it obvious that there is a group of any cardinality?

Comment: @RobArthan Compactness

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks for the clue. I was forgetting about the [Löwenheim–Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Löwenheim–Skolem_theorem). To the OP: that theorem states that any theory (like the theory of groups) that has an infinite model, has models of all infinite cardinalities.

Comment: @RobArthan: $\oplus_{k\in\kappa}\mathbb{Z}$ has cardinality $\kappa$ for any infintie $\kappa$. (And I think your “Thanks for the clue” was meant for spaceisdarkgreen)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: you are right on both counts.

Comment: It seems relevant to mention "there exists a group operation on every nonempty set" is equivalent to the axiom of choice!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: Though AC is not needed if you assume your set is well-orderable, as it is here.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I had to look up what that means, but I think I kinda of tried that, for example in the ordinal 2 you should see that {} + {} = {}, {{}} + {} = {{}}, and {{}}+{{}}={}, but I didn't find doing this particularly enlightening nor easily generalizable. For example, even if we convert the elements of some $\alpha$ into integers mod $\alpha$ this only seems to work for countable ordinals. It's still unclear to me how to go about defining a group on $\omega_1$, let alone the larger ordinals.

Comment: @tox123: You could define a bijection with a group of cardinality $\aleph_1$, and this could be done explicitly, and use that, but as I said, I suspect that's not what you want because that kind of structure has nothing to do with the ordinal structure on $\omega_1$, just with its cardinality. But perhaps  a point to be derived here is that you should specify what kind of properties, if any, you would like this group operation to have, relative to that group structure. You can't do a cyclic group for any uncountable ordinal, that's for sure.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I didn't think much about the group structure at all other than commutativity. My gut instinct was simply to map each finite ordinal to its cyclic counterpart, $\omega_0$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, and maybe $\omega_1$ to either $\mathbb{T}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. I was mostly hoping that there would be some combination of unions, intersections, and other elementary set operations that would create an Abelian group structure on any arbitrary ordinal.